# write a program to store seven fruits in a list entered by the user

Tags: python, coding-style, python-3.10

```
a = input("Name of 1st Fruit:  ")
b = input("Name of 2nd Fruit:  ")
c = input("Name of 3rd Fruit:  ")
d = input("Name of 4th Fruit:  ")
e = input("Name of 5th Fruit:  ")
f = input("Name of 6th Fruit:  ")

l = (a,b,c,d,e,f)
print(l)
```

write a program to store seven fruits in a list entered by the user...
here we use input function to input the seven fruits name and we have to store the names in a list.
after that, what we have to do?

Comment: You stored them in a tuple, not a list.

Comment: You may use a loop to add each in a list, don't create 7 variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple one liner using list comprehension.

```
fruits = [input(f'Enter Fruit {x} \n') for x in range(1, 8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @azro in the comments, it's better to loop and store directly into a list instead of creating 7 different variables, for example:

```
fruits = []
for i in range(1,8):
    fruits.append(input(f"Name of Fruit {i}:  "))
print(fruits)
```

Result:

```
Name of Fruit 1:  Melon
Name of Fruit 2:  Apple
Name of Fruit 3:  Orange
Name of Fruit 4:  Banana
Name of Fruit 5:  Citrus
Name of Fruit 6:  Plum
Name of Fruit 7:  Mandarin
['Melon', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Citrus', 'Plum', 'Mandarin']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop to avoid repeating code. The `append` method will add each fruit to the fruits list.

```
fruits = []
for i in range(7):
    fruit = input("Name of Fruit:  ")
    fruits.append(fruit)

print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = []
v = ["1st", '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th']
for i in v:
    a = input("Enter name of " + v[i]+"fruit:")
    list.append(a)
print(list)
```

you should directly store it in list with the help of for loop and `append` and i made it how u needed it be.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate with `while` loop to store 7 inputs to a list

```
fruits = list()
while len(fruits) < 7: fruits += [input(f"Name of #{len(fruits)+1} Fruit:  ")]
print(fruits)
```

Output:

```
Name of #1 Fruit:  apple
Name of #2 Fruit:  banana
Name of #3 Fruit:  grape
Name of #4 Fruit:  mango
Name of #5 Fruit:  pear
Name of #6 Fruit:  lemon
Name of #7 Fruit:  lime
['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'mango', 'pear', 'lemon', 'lime']
```